Netplan one NIC to access a specific IP, another NIC for the remaining traffic to the Internet
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server with two network interfaces:

(enp0s31f6) connected to a Firewall of a private network with output only to the ip 11.162.66.209
(enp6s0) connected to a 4G router output connected to the Internet.

With Netplan I want to configure that all the requests to the ip 11.162.66.209 go through the NIC (enp0s31f6), and remaining requests to the Internet go through 4G (enp6s0).
I have the following netplan file:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: no
      mtu: 1500
      addresses: [10.0.0.200/24]: [10.0.0.200/24].
      gateway4: 10.0.0.10
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0.0/0
          via: 10.0.0.10
          metric: 200
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.11.10/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.11.1
      mtu: 1500
      routes:
        - to: 11.162.66.209
          via: 192.168.11.1
          metric: 100

With this configuration, if I ping 8.8.8.8, it egresses out the enp0s31f6 interface and is blocked, ignoring the route of the enp6s0 interface.
What error is in the netplan file?
Thank you very much in advance.

What error is in the netplan file? What is in the route table?

Netplan did not trhow any error, the problem was that the outgoing connection was always made through the enp0s31f6 interface that had blocked the internet access. With @TomYan's solution I was able to configure netplan to connect to the internet through the enp6s0 interface.

gateway4: 192.168.11.1

You should remove the line above, because it's equivalent to:
routes:
  - to: 0.0.0.0/0
    via: 192.168.11.1


And you should remove:
routes:
  - to: 0.0.0.0.0/0
    via: 10.0.0.10
    metric: 200

(in which there's the typo 0.0.0.0.0, but whatever)
Because you already have:
gateway4: 10.0.0.10


This is unnecessary when the route destinations (to:) are not the same:
metric: 100

